# error de cofiguración de spring security

Tags: java

Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host 10.9.0.22, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Connection timed out: no further information. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:80) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:326) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    ... 61 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host 10.9.0.22, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Connection timed out: no further information. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".

esto es la cadena de conexio en properties:

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://10.9.0.22:1433;databaseName=BDConectaDesa
spring.datasource.username=Usr_Cob2
spring.datasource.password=concob2$2014
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The TCP/IP connection to the host 10.9.0.22, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Connection timed out: no further information. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall."

Traducción: "El servidor de la BD no responde".

Instala un cliente de BD en la máquina donde quieres ejecutar el programa Java (por ejemplo, SquirrelSQL) y configura la conexión al SQL Server. Cuando consigas conectar, asegúrate que la configuración de tu conexión coincide con la de la BD.

Cosas a comprobar:

- Que el SQL Server está levantado y funcionando (prueba a conectarte en local)
- Que no hay un firewall haciendo drop de las conexiones al SQL Server.
- Que está escuchando en la IP de la intranet (un servidor puede configurarse para que solo acepte peticiones de localhost).
- ...

Comment: Gracias hermano, me sirvió mucho de ayuda.